# Node js: util.inspect add object to array

Tags: node.js

I have a problem where I can not figure out the solution for a long time.

I am using NodeJS and I want to store an object in an array which I receive from an other site via post. I parse this object with formidable and want to display it with util.inspect. In addition I would like to work with that object furthermore and with its properties.

I have my array:

```
const arr = {
    fix: []
};


function CreatePerson (req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
            var firstname = util.inspect(fields.firstname);
            var lastname = util.inspect(fields.lastname);
arr.fix.push(util.inspect(fields));

//Works fine - shows me the two properties of my person with the values
console.log("Person" + util.inspect(fields));

// Works fine - shows me the given firstname
console.log("Firstname: " + util.inspect(fields.firstname));

//This shows me the whole person with all properties as above

console.log("Firstname " + arr.fix[0]);

// If I want to show juste one property it does not work - I get undefined

console.log("Firstname " + arr.fix[0].firstname);
```

How can I access the properties and its values?

The general idea that I have is to create people, store them in an array to work further with them(update, delete), change lastname etc.

Could you please tell me which would be the best solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

`util.inspect(fields)` returns a string representation of the `fields` object (and is mostly used for debugging purposes).

From what I can tell, you want to push the `fields` object *itself* onto the array:

```
arr.fix.push(fields);
```

If you want to log that array, you shouldn't use `+`, as that will cast the array to a string, but pass the array as separate argument:

```
console.log("Firstname", arr.fix[0])
```

Or log it as JSON:

```
console.log("Firstname %j", arr.fix[0])
```